# SQL Update statement that deletes rows if key clash

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table that has two columns Hotel_Guest_ID and Guest_ID that links Guest records to the Hotel details of that guest. The table has the constraint that each pair needs to be unique.

I now have a second table of Prime_ID and Duplicate_ID that was generated after cleaning up the Guest table of duplicates. I would like to go through the Booking table and if the Hotel.Guest_ID is found as a Duplicate_ID, to then replace it with Prime_ID.

```
update b
set h.Guest_ID = gd.Prime_ID
from Hotel as h
join Guest_Duplicates as gd
on h.Guest_ID = gd.Duplicate_ID
```

However this fails as often a Prime_ID already has a record with a specific Guest, at which point I want to just delete this row instead of updating it.

Is there a nice way to do this in a single pass or would I have to delete potential clash rows first, then update in a second query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is a `MERGE` statement. You can insert, update and delete using a single statement. Here's an example -

```
MERGE Table1 AS t1
USING Table2 AS t2
    ON t1.GuestID = t2.DuplicateID
WHEN MATCHED AND (any condition) 
 THEN DELETE
WHEN MATCHED 
 THEN UPDATE SET (assign statement)
WHEN NOT MATCHED 
 THEN
      INSERT(column names)
      VALUES(values to be inserted);
```

Comment: Though what condition would you need to set to only delete if the update was to clash?

Comment: Use `WHEN MATCHED AND EXISTS (check for clash)`.

Comment: so actually this doesn't work. The issue being that the merge statement may update a value, that then clashes with a update against another row. Though merge seems to queue the changes first then apply them, so I have no idea what condition to use that would check against possible clashes from earlier in the merge step

Comment: That just means the `Guest_Dupliactes` table that you generate after cleaning the `Guest` table of duplicates is incorrect? If you generate it the right way, then there should be no case wherein there is an `UPDATE` that clashes against another row. Take care of this when you generate the `Guest_Dupliactes` table.

Comment: The Guest_Duplicates is definitely correct, and the behaviour of the merge is correct. However I'm using a Select against Hotel (Table1) as my 'check for clash' condition and the behaviour of merge is to queue up the the changes until the they've all been checked, then make the changes all at once.

Therefore if the merge statement has two updates that will result in a clash, there's no easy way to check for that in the merge statement as far as I know

Comment: Such a case cannot be checked for in the `MERGE` condition. How about generating `Guest_Duplicates` such that no clashes occur?

Comment: By it's nature guest_duplicates has to be exactly how it is. A link of Prime_ID's to the Dup_ID's that have been merged into it. Therefore as long as there are more than one duplicate row that gets merged into a single prime row then I'm going to run into this issue (in actuality it's thousands of cases)